# Entity for a view Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am new in jhipster and I would like to know  If I can create an entity for a view  like the table with jhipster command ? And how to do it ?

I used jhipster entity command but I am not sure this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JHipster does not support SQL views in Liquibase but JDL lets you flag an entity as read-only which will prevent generating code for creating or updating an entity.

You can then manually adapt generated code to replace table by view, it should be limited to Liquibase migration file.

See official JDL doc for examples: https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/options

`jhipster entity` command also asks you whether new entity should be read-only.

Comment: I don't get error when I do as you say but I would like to understand something . I need to create the ressource , repository and dto manually for this readonly entity ?

Comment: I tested it and it worked fine by creating all expected files. As you can see the Resource template contains conditions on readOnly https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/v6.x_maintenance/generators/entity-server/templates/src/main/java/package/web/rest/EntityResource.java.ejs so I don't understand why it is not created for you.