# Mapping a view instead of a table in springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I know I can map tables easily with jihpster entity command then giving the differents fields of the entity .

But what I want to know is how to map a view in jhipster , springboot , how to define the @Id what is the rule to define it ? Or if a view can have an embedded key ? And in these cases what object do I return ?

Examples are welcome

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64679549/entity-for-a-view-jhipster/64681790?

Comment: Thank you for this link can I have the repository link where you make your requests ? Do you make native query or jpql ? So the entity fields that I define in the domain must  have his fields mapped to each column of the view ?

Comment: Well if you're asking for native query or jpql, I suppose that you're targeting a legacy database. In such case, JHipster can't help you, you must code it manually and there's nothing specific to JHipster in your question, it's pure Spring Data JPA and you can find plenty of resources about it.

Comment: It is possible to map a view as an model in spring :  There are two ways I know to do that manually and generate the model with ** jhipster entity command **  but the difference is the impact on liquibase because generate will create a lot files that you don't really need and you will need to delete them and It also affect the liquibase by creating table for your view .So I think it is better to write your model and other file manually